# Populate select2 dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select, jquery-select2

I have a select2 component that works well with ajax

```
<select id="select_lpr" style="width:100%" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Link a project"></select>
```

and here is how I pull data while searching

```
$("#select_lpr").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    maximumSelectionLength: 5,
    ajax: {
        type  : 'POST',
        url: '../../model/prj.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                wildcardsearch: term, // search term
                data_limit: 10,
                data_offset: 0
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
            return { results: data.dataset};
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
});
```

Now I need to ensure the select is populated on the page load. I am struggling to understand how this can be achieved. I use the latest version of select2 (Version 4).

Comment: it would be great if you share your prj.php.Populating dynamically means you provide a datasource for it what you pass in the url.
The url parameter must contain the datas

Comment: @Andrewboy I suspect if I did not convey the message properly. The snippet above add an option to select2 and is working as expected and the issue at the moment is to devise a mechanism to load the data on load of the page. The php file is huge but it returns a neat json that helps to put the data onto the select2 component.

Comment: <?php
require_once("Util.php");
$utilobj = new Util();
$data_wildcardsearch = $_POST['wildcardsearch']["term"] 
$data_offset = $_POST['data_offset'];
$data_limit = $_POST['data_limit'];

$datarray = array(":wildcardsearch1"=>"%".$data_wildcardsearch."%", ":offset"=>$data_offset, ":limit"=>$data_limit);
$searchquery = "SELECT DATA1 AS id, DATA2 AS text 
                   FROM PRJ A
     WHERE (
       A.NAME LIKE :wildcardsearch1
       ) ORDER BY A.DATA1 DESC LIMIT :offset, :limit ";
$form_data = $utilobj->getBindedData($searchquery, $datarray, "fetchall");
echo json_encode($form_data);

Comment: Number of characters allowed are limited but I have made the code concised for your reference...

Comment: you could edit your question and copy the code there with Update tag.
You have to know that to using select2 you have to have a working select list.Select2 just transform the way of look.